# React.js Increment Count

Tags: reactjs, count, use-state

I have been doing counts, I wanted to make a button increase the two states that I have on the screen, what would be the most optimized ways to do this in bulk?

```
function Lifecicle() {
const [ counter1, setConter1 ] = useState (0);
const [ counter2, setConter2 ] = useState (0);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("counter 1")
    return () => {

    }
}, [counter1])
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("counter 2")
    return () => {

    }
}, [counter2])
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[]")
    return () => {
    }
}, [])
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Clicks c1: {counter1}</h1>
        <h1>Clicks c2: {counter2}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => setConter1(counter1+1)}>
            increment c1
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setConter2(counter2+1)}>
            increment c2
        </button>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Lifecicle;

Answer (score 0):

Just change to one buttone like this:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    setConter1(counter1 + 1);
    setConter2(counter2 + 1);
  }}
>
  increment c1 and c2
</button>
```